# Drupal 8 custom templates tpl

Tags: php, drupal-8

Is there a way to integrate php instead of twig in Drupal8? Twig looks somewhat annoying. But in drupal 7 we could create tpl files with php syntaxes. Is there any way to create tpl files in Drupal 8 too. I am a beginner for drupal.

Comment: It is theoretically possible to use a different template engine, but I'm not aware of a contributed module that provides such a feature. And trying to develop something like that yourself requires a very deep understanding of Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the major and finest change in D8 change template system in twig
in drupal7 no one recommend you to write php code like function or queries or any processing code in theme layer or template file
in drupal 8

> HOOK_preprocess_page

and

> HOOK_preprocess_node

are available same as in drupal 7

you have to write your code what you want in these fuctions and then send to the template what you want to print

like if you want print current user name in your template then do some thing like this

use HOOK function hook_preprocess_page
if you are writing code in your theme then write this code into your .theme file
if in module then in .module file

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;// current user object
  $variables['customUserName'] = $user->getUsername();

}
```

change themename to your theme name if in module then replace with module name
in your twig template you will print this variable like this

```
{{ customUserName }}
```

we are overriding page template so your are able to get this variable in all you page templates
if you need this variable in node template then rename function to

```
function themename_preprocess_node(){}
```

hope this help you
thanks